# Subclassing the UIPageControl for customizing the active and inactive dot image

Tags: ios, swift, uipagecontrol, subclassing

I'm using the UIPageControl for tutorial screen in my app. It's a basic usage of UIPageViewController where user can swipe through info screens to get the essential information about the app usage, while each swipe updates the UIPageControl dots at the screen bottom.

This is how regular dot with tint color looks like

[image: UIPageControl with regular dot]

This is what I would like to do (can be any icon)
[image: UIPageControl with custom icon dot]

What I would like to achieve is to replace the default page control circles with my own images, and set their active and inactive tint color. The reason for this custom implementation is because in the interface builder, only visual parts of page control that can be adjusted are tint and current page color, with the default sized round item.

So I would like to implement the same thing but with my own image for the page control.
An example would be useful.

Answer (score 3):

Here's one example of achieving the desired result

```
class CustomPageControl: UIPageControl {
   let imgActive: UIImage = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "activeImg").withRenderingMode(.alwaysTemplate)
   let imgInactive: UIImage = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "inactiveImg")

   let customActiveYOffset: CGFloat = 5.0
   let customInactiveYOffset: CGFloat = 3.0
   var hasCustomTintColor: Bool = false
   let customActiveDotColor: UIColor = UIColor(rgb: 0xe62f3e, alphaVal: 1.0)

   override var numberOfPages: Int {
       didSet {
           updateDots()
       }
   }

   override var currentPage: Int {
       didSet {
           updateDots()
       }
   }

   override func awakeFromNib() {
       super.awakeFromNib()
       self.pageIndicatorTintColor = .clear
       self.currentPageIndicatorTintColor = .clear
       self.clipsToBounds = false
   }

   func updateDots() {
      var i = 0
      let activeSize = self.imgActive.size
      let inactiveSize = self.imgInactive.size
      let activeRect = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: activeSize.width / 2, height: activeSize.height / 2)
      let inactiveRect = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: inactiveSize.width, height: inactiveSize.height)

      for view in self.subviews {
          if let imageView = self.imageForSubview(view) {
              if i == self.currentPage {
                imageView.image = self.imgActive
                if self.hasCustomTintColor {
                    imageView.tintColor = customActiveDotColor
                }
                imageView.frame = activeRect
                imageView.frame.origin.y = imageView.frame.origin.y - customActiveYOffet
              } else {
                imageView.image = self.imgInactive
                imageView.frame = inactiveRect
                imageView.frame.origin.y = imageView.frame.origin.y - customInactiveYOffset
              }
              i = i + 1
          } else {
              var dotImage = self.imgInactive
              if i == self.currentPage {
                  dotImage = self.imgActive
              }
              view.clipsToBounds = false
              let addedImageView: UIImageView = UIImageView(image: dotImage)
              if dotImage == self.imgActive {
                 addedImageView.frame = activeRect
                 addedImageView.frame.origin.y = addedImageView.frame.origin.y - customActiveYOffet
                if self.hasCustomTintColor {
                    addedImageView.tintColor = customActiveDotColor
                }
             } else {
                 addedImageView.frame.origin.y = addedImageView.frame.origin.y - customInactiveYOffset
             }
             view.addSubview(addedImageView)
             i = i + 1
          }
      }
  }

 func imageForSubview(_ view:UIView) -> UIImageView? {
    var dot: UIImageView?
    if let dotImageView = view as? UIImageView {
        dot = dotImageView
    } else {
        for foundView in view.subviews {
            if let imageView = foundView as? UIImageView {
                dot = imageView
                break
            }
        }
    }
    return dot
}
```

Try it and/or modify and see if it works well.